# move a private github repo to a new account

Tags: github

I created a new github account, and I want to move a private repo from an old account to my new account, and it's important to maintain all histories. After that I want to delete the repo in the old account.

e.g.

> existing github account: **old-user** 
>   existing private repo under the account old-user: **myrepo** 
>   new github account: **new-user**

what should I do?

Comment: Can't just "clone" it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check the [GitHub transfer page](https://help.github.com/articles/how-to-transfer-a-repository):

Transferring between user accounts

- Open the repo's page
- Select "Settings" from the repository action bar
  [image]
- Click the "Transfer" button
  [image]

---

The other option, if you have your repo cloned locally, is to:

```
git push --mirror git@github.com:NewUsername/newProject.git
```

Comment: tried "git push --mirror git@github.com:NewUsername/newProject.git", it worked like magic.  thanks!

Comment: @user342673 yes, the `--mirror` is important if you want to get all your branches and tags.

Answer (score 0):

If forking the repo doesn't work for you (you'll have to add the new-user as a collaborator, I think), you can clone the repo in your computer, and then push it to a new repo in the new-user account.

Lastly, as I always suggest, if your problem is still unresolved, [contact GitHub support team](https://help.github.com/contact), they'll surely be able to help you.